# Is there a way to change `flex-direction` if the contents would wrap using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a table in HTML I'm testing with. Right now, reducing the horizontal window size causes a scrollbar to appear. I would prefer to transpose the table when the window width causes this overflow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><th>table</th><td>attribute 1</td><td>attribute 2</td><td>attribute 3</td><td>attribute 4</td><td>attribute 5</td><td>attribute 6</td></tr>
<tr><th>one</th><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
<tr><th>two</th><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
<tr><th>three</th><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

In my testing I've found that using `flex-direction` lets me transpose the table. For example, when I use the following CSS the table is "normal".

```
tbody {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}
tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
th, td {
    width: 10rem; /* to aid in giving the test table enough width */
}
```

Changing `flex-direction` of `tbody` to `row` and `tr` to `column` causes the table to transpose as I'm looking for.

I've tried to use `flex-wrap`. It successfully acts on the table when the width is reduced, but it only moves one cell/element at a time instead of transposing the entire table.

I can use anything in HTML/CSS but I cannot use Javascript. My last resort is to guess some window width and use an `@media max-width`, but this table will be dynamically generated and so the effective max width would vary greatly. Because of this, I would really like to avoid statically setting some arbitrary magic width for transposition. The best solution would be some way of detecting when a wrap would take place and transposing the entire table (if that's possible to even do without Javascript).

Comment: @SonicBoomNFA That question wasn't appearing for me when I searched it... It does answer the question unless something has changed in 6 years.

Comment: Unfortunately, that limitation still exists today. You'll need JavaScript to accomplish your task.

Comment: It would be a rather disappointing / hacky "fix", but you could add a checkbox to enable/disable "transpose table", then use a :checked & sibling selector like `.my_checkbox:checked + div.table_container_node tbody {}` to modify the styles only when the checkbox is checked.